# What is the Rust way to call a method requireing a string slice from a String

Tags: rust, serde

I'm a rust beginner (but experienced programmer), and I'm trying to create a simple utility function to read data from a json file and am clearly missing important rust-understanding to pull it off. I've looked around but I couldn't make it work from the other rust questions. I'm trying to do something like this:

```rust
pub fn read_data_from_json<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>, P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> T {
    let result = std::fs::read_to_string(path).unwrap();
    return serde_json::from_str(&result).unwrap();
}
```

The problem is that I want to provide the `serde_json::from_str()` with the `&str` it requires, but get a `String` from reading the file. So the rust compiler says:

```
40 |     return serde_json::from_str(&result).unwrap();
   |            ---------------------^^^^^^^-
   |            |                    |
   |            |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
```

The cause is obviously that the `result` variable gets dropped before `from_str()` is done with the value, but I was unable to get 'just the slice' with the value. I've tried `as_str()`, `&*`, `&'static str` and several other options to try to make this work, but I'm clearly missing something, as it seems like a basic use-case. I must admit I'm still a bit fuzzy on 'lifetime' and the involved generics, so the problem might be there.

Comment: This documentation page presents pretty exactly your situation: https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to read [Understanding deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html) from the serde manual. There they suggest `T: DeserializeOwned`, explicitly mentioning your usecase:

> Usually this is because the data that is being deserialized from is going to be thrown away before the function returns, so `T` must not be allowed to borrow from it.

So the solution is:

```rust
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

pub fn read_data_from_json<T: DeserializeOwned, P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> T {
    let result = std::fs::read_to_string(path).unwrap();
    return serde_json::from_str(&result).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Note that this may involve changing the struct into which to deserialize, as it must own its data.

Comment: Okay interesting, but is this then only a problem for serde's way of zero-copy serialization? I figured this is a general thing with borrowing i need to understand. I feel like I should be able to tell Rust to just keep the reference until the function/scope exits, or that I just want the slice and not the string object.

Comment: @leondepeon Rust did keep the reference until the function/scope exited. Your `from_str()` call would be fine if you assigned its result to a local variable and used it inside the function, so it doesn't outlive `result`. But you attempted to *return* the constructed value, and that's not allowed because the zero-copy references inside it would be left dangling once `result` was dropped.